# How can I call a function with differing amount of arguments using a loop?

Tags: c#, function, loops, arguments

The function WriteStartAttribute can be called with 1, 2 or 3 strings as arguments. The amount I want to call it with is dependent on the amount of arguments in writeInfo. To clarify, I want to do the following using a loop:

```
if (writeInfo.Count == 2)
{
    writer.WriteStartAttribute(writeInfo[1]);
}
else if (writeInfo.Count == 3)
{
    writer.WriteStartAttribute(writeInfo[1], writeInfo[2]);
}
else if (writeInfo.Count == 4)
{
    writer.WriteStartAttribute(writeInfo[1], writeInfo[2], writeInfo[4]);
}
```

I tried it using an array (and a List) like this:

```
for (int i = 0; writeInfo.Count() - 1 < i; i += 1)
{
     argumentList[i] = writeInfo[i + 1];
}
writer.WriteStartAttribute(argumentList);
```

However, because no overload accepts an array (or a List) this does not work. 
How can I call a function with differing amount of arguments using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is the [XmlTextWriter.WriteStartAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa336051%28v=vs.71%29), it doesn't accept `params` so you'll have to manually handle it.

Create your own `params` method, and then put your `if` statements in there:

```
void WriteStartAttribute(params string[] values) 
{
     if (values.Length > 4 || values.Length < 2) throw new ArgumentException();
     if (values.Count == 2)
     {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute(values[1]);
     }
     else if (values.Count == 3)
     {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute(values[1], values[2]);
     }
     else if (writeInfo.Count == 4)
     {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute(values[1], values[2], values[4]);
     }
  }
```

Then call that in your loop:

```
WriteStartAttributes(writeInfo);
```

Bonus points for making it an extension method:

```
public static void WriteStartAttribute(this XmlTextWriter writer, params string[] values) 
...

writer.WriteStartAttributes(writeInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the [`params keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a
>   variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the
>   specified type. You also can send no arguments.

```
public void WriteStartAttribute(params string[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// this works:
writer.WriteStartAttribute(writeInfo[1], writeInfo[2], writeInfo[4]);
```

Comment: No, this is the function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartelement.aspx and it has 3 overloads, 1, 2 or 3 strings. I can't change that function.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, using reflection:

```
MethodInfo mi = writer.GetType().GetMethod(WriteStartAttribute);
mi.Invoke(instance, argumentList);
```

The invoke function take an array of argument to be passed to the function. This seems to be what you are expecting.

I'm not a big fan of using reflection where there is a possible manual (longer) way of doing so.